# How can I make source block in org mode to be scrollable?

Tags: org-mode

As the title says, I'm trying to make the source blocks, when export, to be scrollable (e.g. vertical) so that the long source blocks don't mess up with the rest of content and the html/pdf files look neat in this way.
After doing some research, I've found a html way to do it, a little bit ugly, by adding html export block before the coding block

```
#+begin_export html
<pre style="height: 300px; overflow: scroll;">
#+end_export
#+begin_src python
very very long long source code
#+end_src
```

It exports as like
[image]
Which looks like nested blocks, but what I want is to make the source block can scroll itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set it for all your Org files you can use the following lines in your init file:

```el
(setq org-html-head "<style type=\"text/css\">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
      pre.src {
        height: 100px;
        overflow: auto;
      }
    /*]]>*/
   </style>")
```

For a single Org file set the corresponding export property within the Org file instead:

```org
#+HTML_HEAD: <style type="text/css">/*<![CDATA[*/ pre.src { height: 100px; overflow: auto; } /*]]>*/ </style>
```

Thereby, adapt the `height` attribute to your needs.